# post data is not storing correctly in database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to store post data into database and i have dynamically generated fields `course[]`, `start_date[]` etc and  i write following code to retrieve and store post data:

but after execution of below only '0' zeros are storing in all fields.

```
if($this->input->post('course'))
{

    $education_data= array();
    for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['course']); $i++)
    {
        $education = array(
                'course'       => $this->input->post('course' . $i),
                'start_date'   => $this->input->post('start_date' . $i),
                'end_date'     => $this->input->post('end_date' . $i),
                'college_name' => $this->input->post('college_name' . $i),
                'other_info'   => $this->input->post('other_info' . $i),
        );

        $this->db->insert('education',$education);
    }
}
```

so then i tried second method:

```
if($this->input->post('course'))
{    

    $courses = $this->input->post("course");
    $startdates = $this->input->post("start_date");
    $end_date = $this->input->post("end_date");
    $college_name = $this->input->post("college_name");
    $other_infos   = $this->input->post("other_info");

    $education_data= array();
    for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['course']); $i++)
    {

        $education = array(
                 'course'       => $courses[$i],
                 'start_date'   => $startdates[$i],
                 'end_date'     => $end_date[$i],
                 'college_name' => $college_name[$i],
                 'other_info'   => $other_infos[$i],    //line number 101
        );

        // Insert Education data in 'education' table
        $this->db->insert('education',$education);
    }
}
```

But in this case only one iteration is running and at second iteration it is giving some error in second iteration of loop.

error in second iteration:

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 1

Filename: models/resume_model.php

Line Number: 101


A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1048

Column 'other_info' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `education` (`course`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `college_name`, `other_info`) VALUES ('', '', '', '', NULL)

Filename: C:\wamp\www\resume\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

If anybody know please suggest a solution.

var_dump output:

```
 [course] => Array
        (
            [0] => course1
            [1] => course2
        )

    [start_date] => Array
        (
            [0] => from1
            [1] => from2
        )

    [end_date] => Array
        (
            [0] => to1
            [1] => to2
        )

    [college_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => univ1
            [1] => univ2
        )

    [other_info] => Array
        (
            [0] => other1
        )
```

Comment: what is the error given in the second iteration?

Comment: First of all, don't use a `for` loop. Use a `foreach`. Secondly, verify what the contents of your variables are by using a `var_dump()` call.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what `var_dump($_POST)` might look like?

Comment: @JoseVega I have updated above question with error

Comment: Where do you "have dynamically generated fields course[], ..."? In form post? I suspect not...

Comment: @ghbarratt  I have updated var_dump in question

Comment: @all thanks after debugging , i got whats was going wrong . Now my problem is solve Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update for var_dump**

From the var_dump you can see that other_info will not have a `'other_info'   => $other_infos[1]` because there's only one item in the array. You can add another index to other_info if you would like for your seconds code to work correctly.

**Update for @JoseVega I have updated above question with error**

You error is stating that the value passed for other_info is null, from the error I would assume that your table schema does not support a null value for other_info column. You can either change your schema to allow null values or you can pass it a value when its null.

Try the following, and see your results. I am assuming that not all arrays are of the same size and thats why your second iteration fails.

```
    for($i=0; $i<count($courses); $i++) {

         $education = array(
                    'course'       => isset($courses[$i]) ? $courses[$i] : "",
                    'start_date'   => isset($startdates[$i]) ? $startdates[$i] : "",
                    'end_date'     => isset($end_date[$i]) ? $end_date[$i] : "",
                    'college_name' => isset($college_name[$i]) ? $college_name[$i] : "",
                    'other_info'   => isset($other_infos[$i]) ? $other_infos[$i] : "",
                    );

         // Insert Education data in 'education' table
         $this->db->insert('education',$education);
    }
```

Comment: That would only hide the underlying problem (not posting what he expects he is posting)

Comment: @ErwinMoller I don't think its an underlying problem, I feel like the value of other_info is not required and when the form is submitted the value for other_info is null and therefore causing the error he is seeing. Its a case of making sure that value is set and if it isn't passing something else besides null.

Comment: @JoseVega thanks after viewing var_dump , i got a syntax error in script.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$_POST['course'] <-- contains an array, as you stated.

So if you would print_r($POST); you would see something like:

```
array(2) {
  ["course"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "17740"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "18422"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "14170"
  }
  ["startdate"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2012-01-02"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "2012-01-02"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "2012-01-02"
  }
```

But in your FIRST code-example you use:

$this->input->post('course' . $i),

Which doesn't exist (course12345 doesn't exist).

In your second code-example, you do it right:

```
$courses = $this->input->post("course");
```

Now $courses holds the array, which you seem to use right in your loop on casual inspection (maybe I miss something).

I suspect you best start debugging with a simple

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

and make very sure you receive what you expected to receive.
I suspect you don't post everything you think you are posting.

Make sure you have as many elements in all used arrays as you have in your courses array.

It is hard to advice more without seeing the actual content of $_POST.

Comment: I see. Jose Vega is already zooming in on your problem, and he is right, so I leave your problem to him, and move on. Good luck!